# Formatting in a text game

Tags: java

I have a simple program that asks for the user's name. I want the space where the user enters his/her name to be next to the line that says "Name: " rather than below it. I know this is a very basic question, but I've already searched through the Java documentation, as well as questions already asked on stackoverflow and I still can't find the answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private String name;
    private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void enterName() {
        System.out.println("Please enter your name");
        System.out.println("Name: ");
        name = sc.nextLine();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.enterName();
    }
}
```

Comment: `println`: read the documentation for that.

Comment: also, relevant documentation for reading from command line: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `print` instead of `println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html):

```
System.out.print("Name: ");
```